# Generating exactly prime number with Java

Tags: java, biginteger, random, primes

I'm aware of the function BigInteger.probablePrime(int bitLength, Random rnd) that outputs probably prime number of any bit length. I want a REAL prime number in Java. Is there any FOSS library to do so with acceptable performance? Thanks in advance!

### EDIT:

I'm looking at 1024 & 2048 bit primes.

Comment: Are you sure you need real prime numbers? In most cases, relative prime is good enough. Most RSA keys are generated with relative prime numbers.

Comment: you probably do *not* want to write any cryptography stuff if you don't understand that it's more probable that you get struck by lightning the day you won the national lottery than it is probable that *probablePrime* gets you a non-prime number (when correctly called).  It's all about probabilities :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- use probable prime to generate a candidate
- use a [fast deterministic test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Fast_deterministic_tests) such as the [AKS primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#Algorithm) to check whether the candidate is indeed prime.

---

**edit:** Or, if you don't trust the isProbablePrime to be large enough certainty, use the BigInteger constructor [`BigInteger(int bitLength, int certainty, Random rnd)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20int,%20java.util.Random)) that lets you tune your certainty threshold:

> certainty - a measure of the uncertainty that the caller is willing to tolerate. The probability that the new BigInteger represents a prime number will exceed (1 - 1/2<sup>certainty</sup>). The execution time of this constructor is proportional to the value of this parameter.

Probabilistic tests used for cryptographic purposes are guaranteed to bound the probability of false positives -- it's not like there's some gotcha numbers that exist that will sneak through, it's just a matter of how low you want the probability to be. If you don't trust the Java BigInteger class to use these (it would be nice if they documented what test was used), use the [Rabin-Miller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) test.

Comment: +1 - however, it should be noted that the worst case of AKS is `O((logN)^12)`.  That is fast compared with factorizing a prime `N`, but not fast in absolute terms.

Comment: "Adding certainty surely increases security" -- you can be fairly certain but not absolutely certain. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There are some methods to generate very large primes with acceptable performance, but not with sufficient density for most purposes other than getting into the Guiness Book of Records.

Look at it like this: the likelihood that a number returned by `probablePrime()` is not prime is lower than the likelihood of you and everyone you know getting hit by lighting. Twice. On a single day.

Just don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for cryptographically secure random prime numbers.

Comment: @Viet, I'm assuming you want to implement an RSA algorithm? Even the official implementations of these need to use probable primes.

Comment: the cryptographic community uses probable prime tests to generate cryptographically secure random prime numbers.

Comment: @teehoo: they don't *need* to use probable primes, but in practice they do.

Comment: @Jason, I meant if they want to find a prime in an acceptable amount of time they need to :)

Comment: So "probable" is an understatement, but they didn't want to name the method `almostAlwaysButOnceInABlueMoonNotPrime()`... ;-)

Comment: @Viet: Then use probablePrime(). That's what is for. Nobody in the whole wide world knows a better method. And if they did, it would most likely mean that prime-based cryptography has become useless.

Comment: Thanks guys! @teehoo: Any proof of that statement? I know that OpenSSL uses probably prime numbers http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_generate_prime.html .

Comment: "there is no software, FOSS or otherwise, that can decide in acceptable time whether a given large number is prime or not." -- not necessarily true

Comment: @Jason: right, I learned something from your post and removed that statement, though it still hinges on the definition on "acceptable time".

Comment: @Viet, check out "Choice of p and q" at http://project.cyberpunk.ru/idb/cryptography.html

This article was published by NIST sometime ago.

Comment: @Michael: agreed. devil's always in the details. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the constructor of `BigInteger` to generate a real prime:

```
BigInteger(int bitLength, int certainty, Random rnd)
```

The time to execute is proportional to the certainty, but on my Core i7 it isn't a problem.

Comment: I ran some tests on a 1535 bit random number with a certainty from 0 up to 500 and I can find no increase in computation time. So either something goes wrong in my test or the certainty has no influence.

Answer (score 1):

Make a method and wrap it.

```
BigInteger definitePrime(int bits, Random rnd) {
    BigInteger prime = new BigInteger("4");
    while(!isPrime(prime)) prime = BigInteger.probablePrime(bits,rnd);
    return prime;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, did you understand what I want?

Comment: How do you think isPrime works? It's probably the same test that probablePrime uses to determine if the random number is prime.

Comment: @RoelStorms Interestingly enough, this answer (from 5 years ago) has the same basic properties as the accept answer. Make a probable prime and continue to test it until you're sure it's composite.

Comment: I accept with @Silver how we can write the isPrime method?

Comment: There are numerous ways of determining whether or not a number is prime or not, all of which are beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rnd = new SecureRandom();
System.out.println(BigInteger.probablePrime(bitLength, rnd));
```

The probability that a `BigInteger` returned by method `probablePrime()` is composite does not exceed 2^-100.